# How do I validate extra pin field on my WordPress login form page?

Tags: plugin-development, login, advanced-custom-fields, wp-login-form, code

I have been able to add an extra field to my WordPress login form using the following code inside wp_login.php file, thanks to stackxchange.

```
add_action('login_form','my_added_login_field');
function my_added_login_field(){
    //Output your HTML
?>
    <p>
        <label for="my_extra_field">Pin<br>
        <input type="text" tabindex="20" size="20" value="" class="input" id="my_extra_field" name="my_extra_field_name"></label>
    </p>
<?php
}
```

I need help to validate/connect the new custom field to a data column in wp_users called serials. I want users to be able to login if their username, password and new serial number from database is correct/exists.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Be sure to format any code in your questions/answers as code so that it gets formatted correctly.  Use the {} button in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that where you said "I need help to validate/connect the new custom field to a data column in `wp_users` called serials" that you actually meant `wp_usermeta` field where the meta key is "serials".

To validate any additional fields as part of the login, you use the [`wp_authenticate_user` filter.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate_user/)

Start by checking to see if `$user` is a WP error, and if it is, there's no point in continuing as the login failed anyway.  If it's not an error, move on to check if your custom field is empty as you'll want to make sure it's filled out.  If the field is empty, return an error.

Lastly, if it's a valid user and the value is given in the field, then retrieve the db value (as mentioned above, assuming this is a user meta key in wp_usermeta since there are not custom fields in wp_users). If comparing the values fails, return an error.

```
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'my_validate_pin', 10, 2 );
function my_validate_pin( $user, $password ) {

    // Validate PIN if we're not already in an error.
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
        $pin = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'serials', true );

        // Error if field is empty.
        if ( ! isset( $_POST['my_extra_field_name'] ) ) {
            remove_action( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20 );
            $user = new WP_Error( 'failed', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: Must include PIN") );
        }

        // Assuming you're looking for form value to match the db value.
        if ( $pin != $_POST['my_extra_field_name'] ) {
            // If values don't match, return error
            remove_action( 'authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20 );
            $user = new WP_Error( 'failed', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid PIN") );
        }

    }

    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much butlerblog, it worked very well...

Comment: That's great! If it worked well, could you mark the answer as accepted?